# How can I use Python to automate setting a password using the Unix pass command line program

Tags: python, linux, command-line-interface, popen

I'm trying to automate setting new passwords using the Unix pass program.
I understand that there is a Python library, [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), that might help, but I would like to avoid using third-party libraries.

**When using a terminal, the flow looks like this:**

```
$ pass insert --force gmail
>> Enter password for gmail: <type in password using masked prompt>
>> Retype password for gmail: <reenter password>
```

**What I would like my function to do:**

1. Run the command `pass insert --force {entry_name}`
2. Capture the output (and echo it for testing)
3. Check output for the presence of 'password for gmail', and if True

   - write '{password}\n' to stdin
   - write '{password}\n' to stdin again
4. Echo any errors or messages for testing

**Issues:**

I'm stuck on step 2. The subprocess either hangs indefinitely, times out with an error, or produces no output.

**Attempts:**

- I've tried configurations of Popen(), using both stdin.write() and communicate().
- I've set wait() calls at various points.
- I've tried both the shell=True and shell=False options (prefer False for security reasons)

---

**Code**:

```
def set_pass_password(entry_name, password):
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

    command = ['pass', 'insert', '--force', entry_name]

    sub = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

    # At this point I assume that the command has run, and that there is an "Enter password..." message
    message = sub.stdout.read()  # also tried readline() and readlines()
    print(message) # never happens, because process hangs on stdout.read()

    if 'password for {}'.format(entry_name) in message:
        err, msg = sub.communicate(input='{p}\n{p}\n'.format(p=password))
        print('errors: {}\nmessage: {}'.format(err, msg))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: the original answer was about `passwd`, which is what's used to **set** passwords. I noticed late that you use `pass`, which is a keystore (doesn't actually change the Unix password). The `pass` program works differently and **will not** print a prompt if `stdin` is not a tty. Therefore the following very simple program works:

```
def set_pass_password(entry_name, password):
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

    command = ['pass', 'insert', '--force', entry_name]

    sub = Popen(command, bufsize=0, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

    err, msg = sub.communicate(input='{p}\n{p}\n'.format(p=password))
    print('errors: {}\nmessage: {}'.format(err, msg))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    set_pass_password("ttt", "ttt123asdqwe")
```

(you will see that both stderr and stdout are empty, if the command succeeded).

For the `passwd` command:

FYI: the `passwd` command outputs the prompt to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

NOTE: rather than sending the password twice in the same 'write', you **might** need to wait for the second prompt before sending the password again.

For this simple case, code similar to yours should work, but in general you should use `select` on all the pipes and send/receive data when the other side is ready, so you don't get deadlocks.

Comment: changing the program to check for `stderr` instead of `stdout` did not change the outcome. It sill hangs at `stderr.read()`. When using `msg, err = sub.communicate()` after `Popen()`, both msg and err are blank. Could you provide a working example of executing `pass insert xxx` and somehow outputting the first message "Insert password for xxx":?

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I did need to add `universal_newlines=True` or set the encoding in the `Popen` constructor, but other than that, it worked. Out of curiosity, is the behavior of not printing to non-TTY devices something Linux/Unix does or is it specific to pass. I couldn't find much from the rather limited documentation available.